# Matching massive amount of coordinates from two lists

Tags: algorithm, hashmap, comparison, matching, similarity

I'm searching for an more efficient Algorithm to match coordinates between two lists.

Given are two Lists with Lat/Long Values. My goal is it to find for every Coordinate in the first list, all matching coordinates from the other list in a given Radius, like 500 meters for example.

Right now it's just brute forced by two for loops, just doing the calculation of the distance and checking if its within my radius for every coordinate. But that brings me to a complexity of O(n²).

To improve this, my first idea would be to do something similar to a Hashmap:
Classify the first list to bigger "fields" by cutting off some decimals at the end. An example would be:

- lat: 44.7261 long: 8.2831 -> **lat: 44.72 long: 8,28**
- lat: 43.8102 long: 9.7612 -> lat: 43.81 long: 9.76
- lat: 44.7281 long: 8.2899 -> **lat: 44.72 long: 8,28**

So some "groups" of coordinates are created.
Now I only need to iterate once over the second list and looking in which group a specific coordinate lies and do the Calculation with all Coordinates in that group.
Visually you could describe the idea of creating squares in the map that are my Hashs. Then first looking in what hash the current coordinate lies and comparing all coordinates in that hash with the current one.

Like this I can reduce the complexity from O(n²) to O(n+m*(average_size_of_groups))
If a coordinate will be at the border of a group I'll need to check the neighbours of this group too.

But somehow I believe there is a more efficient way to match these two lists. I was looking for algorithms that treat such kind of problems, but my google searches weren't successful.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is pretty good, but the best size for your groups is smaller than you seem to be guessing, and that means you're doing too many comparisons.

Instead of just cutting off a few decimal places, you should divide the points into squares that are the same size as your radius.

Then each point is compared with the points it its own group and the 8 neighboring groups.

Comment: yes, the example was taken out of nowhere, without testing it. I used it to clearify my idea of the algorithm.
Is there any litarature to such an algorithm where i could read further and refer to?

Answer (score 0):

A common optimization for this kind of thing is to pre-process your array of points and create a two-dimensional array of "buckets", with each bucket holding a list of points.. One dimension is the latitude, and the other is longitude. If you want a granularity of 500 meters, then each bucket represents a 500x500 meter square.

You'll need a way to map a lat/lon value to an x/y value for your matrix. You decide what lat/lon will correspond to your 0,0 matrix square. Then, to compute the lat/lon for any point, you subtract the offset (the lat/lon from 0,0), and convert the latitude and longitude to meters. Then divide each by 500 and put the point in the resulting bucket.

This gets a little tricky, of course, because the distance between degrees of longitude depends on the latitude, as described in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142326/calculating-longitude-length-in-miles.

Now, when somebody says "Give me all the points within 500 meters of Austin", you can get the lat/lon of Austin, convert to bucket coordinates as described above, and then compare that with all the points from that bucket and the 8 surrounding buckets.

The size of the array is the range of latitude, converted to meters and divided by 500, multiplied by the range of longitude, also converted to meters and divided by 500.

The Earth's circumference of approximately 40,100 km gives you a estimated maximum size of this array: 80,200 x 80,200, or about 6.432 billion buckets if you want your buckets to be 500 meters. If you want to cover that large a range, you'll probably want to use a sparse matrix representation.